Requirements for small spacecraft attitude determination and control system (ADCS) from the point of view of systems engineering and control
Are there currently any practical, well-founded basic requirements for small spacecraft orientation systems that can be used as a starting point for mission development?
Explanations: The main purpose of the attitude control system is to orient the spacecraft in the right direction with the required degree of accuracy. From this point of view, the designer must formulate the requirements (established by the flight objectives), evaluate the force-torque characteristics, select the appropriate equipment (engines, sensors and algorithms to ensure the specified orientation). At first glance, the task is simple. But when we go down one level, questions such as:

required accuracy of the attitude control system (in terms of speeds/angular position)
speed control range
required quality indicators of transient processes (degree of oscillation, overshoot, control time, etc.)
overload capacity of electric motors (ratio of the ultimate torque to the nominal torque)

First, I would like to see what paths have been trodden and what solutions have been tested in practice, i.e. build on accumulated practical experience.
Question: What are the practically justified basic requirements for attitude control systems for small spacecraft from the point of view of system engineering and control?

This is probably too broad for a stack exchange question since it would take a textbook to answer it.

I’m voting to close this question because it is far too broad. As noted in another comment, this is the kind of question that needs an entire textbook for a proper answer. There are multiple textbooks and scientific journal articles on this very topic.

I don't think closing is the only/best course of action here. I do think the feedback on improving the question could be more specific. For example: 1) Define the acronym ADCS somewhere, 2) If you're going for basic requirements, don't ask for an explanation of how each spec is determined.

@phil1008 I have deciphered the abbreviation. But I need to know exactly "how". Where can I find out "how"?

If you are looking just to get a sense of the complexity or a general jist of what work is ahead of you there is lots of information available from Academia mostly for the cubesats. Many university projects publish their PDRs and CDRs- these will likely contain some snippets of the requirements document in the appendices.
However if you are looking to use the said requirements remember that each spacecraft is unique and the mission requirements will be as well. Therefore the requirements for the ADCS will vary widely.

You understood my question correctly. I decided that I really could use some starting point. But more than anything else, it is important for me to understand the reasons for the requirements. I will try to figure this out myself.
